# error: "data is not aligned" from Eigen when performing bundle adjustment with g2o

Tags: c++, optimization, eigen3, slam, g2o

I defined a derived class with g2o:

```
 class EdgeProjectXYZ2UVPoseOnly: public g2o::BaseUnaryEdge<2,Eigen::Vector2d,g2o::VertexSE3Expmap>
  {
    public:
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
    virtual void computeError();
    virtual void linearizeOplus();
    virtual bool read(std::istream& in) {}
    virtual bool write(std::ostream& os) const {}

    Vector3d point_;
    Camera* camera_;    

  };
```

I rewrite computerError() and linearizeOplus():

```
void EdgeProjectXYZ2UVPoseOnly::computeError()
  {
    const g2o::VertexSE3Expmap* pose=static_cast<const g2o::VertexSE3Expmap*>(_vertices[0]);
    _error=_measurement-camera_->camera2pixel(pose->estimate().map(point_));
  }

  void EdgeProjectXYZ2UVPoseOnly::linearizeOplus()
  {
    g2o::VertexSE3Expmap* pose=static_cast<g2o::VertexSE3Expmap*>(_vertices[0]);
    g2o::SE3Quat T(pose->estimate());
    Vector3d xyz_trans=T.map(point_);
    double x=xyz_trans[0];
    double y=xyz_trans[1];
    double z=xyz_trans[2];
    double zz=z*z;

    _jacobianOplusXi(0,0)=x*y*camera_->fx_/zz;
    _jacobianOplusXi(0,1)=-(1+x*x/zz)*camera_->fx_;
    _jacobianOplusXi(0,2)=y*camera_->fx_/z;
    _jacobianOplusXi(0,3)=-camera_->fx_/z;
    _jacobianOplusXi(0,4)=0;
    _jacobianOplusXi(0,5)=x*camera_->fx_/zz;

    _jacobianOplusXi(1,0)=camera_->fy_*(1+y*y/zz);
    _jacobianOplusXi(1,1)=-x*y*camera_->fy_/zz;
    _jacobianOplusXi(1,2)=-x*camera_->fy_/z;
    _jacobianOplusXi(1,3)=0;
    _jacobianOplusXi(1,4)=-camera_->fy_/z;
    _jacobianOplusXi(1,5)=y*camera_->fy_/zz;

  }
```

Optimizing poses via following codes(variables *Tcr_estimated_* and *inliners* result from outputs of `cv::solvePnPRansac()`):

```
 typedef g2o::BlockSolver<g2o::BlockSolverTraits<6,2>> Block; 
     Block::LinearSolverType* linearSolver=new g2o::LinearSolverDense<Block::PoseMatrixType>();
     Block* solver_ptr=new Block(linearSolver);
     g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg* solver=new g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg(solver_ptr);
     g2o::SparseOptimizer optimizer;
     optimizer.setAlgorithm(solver);

     g2o::VertexSE3Expmap* pose=new g2o::VertexSE3Expmap();
     pose->setId(0);
     pose->setEstimate(g2o::SE3Quat(Tcr_estimated_.rotation_matrix(),Tcr_estimated_.translation()));     
     optimizer.addVertex(pose);

     for(int i=0;i<inliers.rows;i++)
     {
       int index=inliers.at<int>(i,0);
       myVO::EdgeProjectXYZ2UVPoseOnly* edge=new myVO::EdgeProjectXYZ2UVPoseOnly();
       edge->setId(i);
       edge->setVertex(0,pose);
       edge->point_=Vector3d(pts3d[index].x,pts3d[index].y,pts3d[index].z);
       edge->camera_=curr_->camera_.get();
       edge->setMeasurement(Vector2d(pts2d[index].x,pts2d[index].y));
       edge->setInformation(Eigen::Matrix2d::Identity());     
       optimizer.addEdge(edge);
     }     

     optimizer.initializeOptimization();    
     optimizer.optimize(10);
```

While running the whole system, the terminal gave following error information:

```
 /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MapBase.h:168:void Eigen::MapBase<Derived, 0>::checkSanity() const [with Derived = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 6, 0, 2, 6>, 32, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >]: suppose '((size_t(m_data) % (((int)1 >= (int)internal::traits<Derived>::Alignment) ? (int)1:  (int)internal::traits<Derived>::Alignment)) == 0) && "data is not aligned"'fails.
```

I confirms problem comes from the optimization parts. Who can help?

Comment: It worked when I appened `set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" )` in my CMakeLists.txt, but I don't know why.

Comment: Please run it in a debugger and look at the backtrace to find both the call to Map and the data that are not compatible.

Comment: Release will make your code skip the Eigen assert. So the problem still exists but may cause some crash later. Example of a similar situation here: https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/issues/557#issuecomment-988426510